# Invertibility of $I-A$ if the spectral radius of the operator $A$ is less than $1$

Tags: real-analysis, spectral-theory

I want an explication of the following fact:

If the spectral radius of a bounded operator $A$ on a Banach space is less than one, then $I - A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 5):

If $\rho(A)<1$, then the operator $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n$$ is defined (why?) and is in fact $(I-A)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

This is trivial from the definition of spectrum.  If the spectral radius is less than one, then in particular $1$ is not in the spectrum, which means $I-A$ is invertible.

Cameron Buie has answered a more interesting question.

Answer (score 2):

You can find hint at [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) wikipedia article. Furthermore the question is maybe a duplicate, I think you can find the answer [at math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=neumann%20series).